# Can't able to delete meta data records in my dev org to delete/ uninstall a managed package

Tags: managed-package, custom-metadata

I have tried to uninstall a managed package from my dev org and got failed to remove the components because I had some custom metadata records to remove from the org. But when I try to delete those records I encountered the following error page. Did anyone experience this?

[image]

Comment: Aren't you system admin in your org?

Comment: No. I am the System Admin.

Comment: Maybe try it in classic? The Lightning UI for custom metadata is still a bit patchy in my experience

Comment: No luck. Same error page at classic as well.

Comment: This seems to be a data issue inserted while installing app from appexchange. Please raise the salesforce ticket.